# WinRT/C++ co_await resume_foreground(Dispatcher()) cause try_as runtime error

Tags: c++-winrt, winrt-async

What causes the `try_as()` runtime error to occur when calling `co_await resume_foreground(Dispatcher())` in the `LoadOverallStatisticsAsync()` function.
[image: try_as() runtime error]

Note: using `resume_foreground(Dispatcher())` is only for the purpose of ensuring that the function runs on the UI Thread.

**HomePage.cpp**

```
fire_and_forget HomePage::HomeLoaded(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    loadAction = [lifetime = get_strong()]() -> winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction
    {
        ...
        co_await lifetime->LoadOverallStatisticsAsync();
        ...
    }();

    co_await loadAction;
}

winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction HomePage::LoadOverallStatisticsAsync()
{
    co_await resume_foreground(Dispatcher()); // try_as() runtime error occurs here

    apartment_context ui_thread;
    co_await resume_background();

    // DoThings();

    co_await ui_thread;

    // Update UI
}
```

Edit: this code is run on a UWP project in a WinRT/C++ Desktop environment

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Does `HomePage` derive from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` or `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page`?

Comment: The exception indicates that your `this` pointer is a null pointer. This can be the result of passing (const) references into co-routines. You are doing it in the code presented, maybe you are doing it in other code as well.

Comment: `HomePage` does derive from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page`

Comment: So, is there any solution to solve that problem?

Comment: The code provided isn't sufficient to reproduce the issue. A [mcve] is required.